# Как конвертировать текстовый файл из UTF-8 в RUSSIAN_CIS.RU8PC866?

Tags: кодировка, notepad++

Не нашел такой возможности в notepad++ (именно такой кодировки) и варианты кончились. Нужно как-то пересохранить в этом представлении.

Comment: У меня сомнения по поводу PC866. Может все таки cp866? Такая была во времена MS-DOS.

Comment: @defrag Не, едва ли. В остальных батниках стоит PC866. Сохранил исполняемый файл в utf8 и теперь в строковых константах крякозябры ._.

Comment: Странно... даже всемогущий iconv ничего про такую кодировку не знает. Может ошибка изначально в батники закралась?

Comment: @defrag Но ведь остальные работают..

Comment: Всё, приплыли. Безвозвратно утеряны русские строки. Весь вечер делал =(